# groupby and add some rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  c  3
3  c  4
4  e  5
```

I would like to get summing result below.key = column A

```
df.B.groupby(df.A).agg(np.sum)
```

But I want to add specific row.

```
   B
a  3
b  0
c  7
d  0
e  5
f  0
```

but I should add row "b" and "d"."f"

How can I get this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reindex`

```
df.groupby('A').B.sum().reindex(list('abcdef'), fill_value=0)

A
a    3
b    0
c    7
d    0
e    5
f    0
Name: B, dtype: int64
```